# How to dynamically define nested routes in express/node.js

Tags: html, node.js, express, routes

I'm pretty new to the `express/nodejs` and would like to apply a route such that routes are dynamically adapted based on the article name.
The articles are saved within `articles.js` consisting of

```
const articles = [{
  title: 'article1',
  link: 'article2',
  creator: 'Anna',
  createdAt: '17/10/2021',
  description: 'Test description',
  publish: 'True'
},
{
  title: 'article2',
  link: 'article2',
  creator: 'Sascha',
  createdAt: '17/10/2021',
  description: 'Test description',
  publish: 'True'
},
{
  title: 'article3',
  link: 'article3',
  creator: 'Anna',
  createdAt: '17/10/2021',
  description: 'Test description',
  publish: 'True'
}]

exports.articles = articles;
```

In a seperate file I'm defining my routes in `index.js`:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()


//load arcticles 
const Articles = require('../articles/articles');



// ----Routing----
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    const articles = await Articles.articles.filter(all => all.publish ==='True')
    res.render("index", {articles: articles});
});

router.get("/route1", async (req, res) => {
    const articles = await Object.values(Articles.articles).filter(all => all.publish ==='True');
    res.render("route1", {articles: articles});
});



router.get("/route1/:link", async (req, res, next) => {
    const articles = await Object.values(Articles.articles).filter(all => all.publish ==='True');
    var name = req.params.link;
    return res.json({ message: 'Users Show', Articles: name});
});

module.exports = router
```

However, when trying to access these via my HTML file, this doesnt seem to work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="author" content="" />
        <title>Clean Blog - Start Bootstrap Theme</title>
        <link href="../css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Main Content-->
        <div class="container px-4 px-lg-5">
            <div class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-7">
                    <!-- Post preview-->
                    <div class="post-preview">
                            <% articles.forEach(article => { %>
                                <h2 class="post-title" style="margin-bottom: -1.41rem"><a href="futureai?id=<%= article.link %>", id="route1/"><%= article.title %></a></h2>
                            
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Footer-->
        <footer class="border-top">
            
        </footer>
        <!-- Bootstrap core JS-->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Core theme JS-->
        <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I suppose that within the HTML file the routes cannot be catched properly, however I cannot tell how why this is the case.

Comment: Usually dynamic routes are implemented by defining one route with parameters in it and then the code in that route uses the parameters to look up dynamic content and respond accordingly.  This is generally a lot better than manually registering new routes to match every new piece of dynamic content.  Parameters in routes can be either in the path or in the query string - depending upon a number of factors.

Comment: Thank you. that's what helped me to solve my question.